# Promise object traversing a method calls sequence (as return type)

Tags: typescript, promise

There is this old/classic approach - method return result of other method call:

```
method1(): ObjectX {
   if( condition1 )
      return method2();

   return undefined // or some default value;
}

method2(): ObjectX {
  let res: ObjectX;
  // some IO operations
  return res;
}
```

Now I want to use `Promise<ObjectX>` as return type of method2 (for example because there are some IO operations).

So method2 becomes:

```
method2() : Promise<ObjectX> {
  return new Promise((resolve)=> {
     let res: ObjectX;
     // some IO operations
     resolve(res);
  })
}
```

The problem is in method1.

Why IT CAN NOT BE something like this:

```
method1() : Promise<ObjectX> {
   if( condition1) 
      return this.method2(); 

   return new Promise((reject)=> { reject(‘error’); })
}
```

Why a method that needs to return a promise CAN NOT return the result of another method (being a similar Promise) ?

Why it has to 'open' the received promise, take out the result and resolve it's own Promise with this result?

Like this:

```
method1() : Promise<ObjectX> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if( condition1) 
          method2().then( (r) => resolve(r) ); // take out the result from received promise and resolve my own promise :(

       reject(‘error’); 
    });
```

}

I mean this works, but I want to understand why previous method1, does not work.

More generally, suppose I have a sequence of methods that call each other and returning an object (return object traverse the sequence). If I introduce a Promise in the last method - as result type, I have to heavily modify the code of all methods in the sequence, not only the signature and return statements.

Or is there another technique to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your final `method1` is vastly overcomplicated:

```
method1() {
   if(condition1) 
      return Promise.resolve(method2());
   return Promise.reject(‘error’); 
}
```

No need for a return type: typescript will correctly work out that it is `Promise<ObjectX>`.

But even that is overcomplicated:

```
async method1() {
   if(condition1) 
      return method2();
   throw 'error';
}
```

and again `method1` has the correct return type of `Promise<ObjectX>`.

Either of these is the same whether `method2()` returns `ObjectX` or `Promise<ObjectX>`. You should never need to "unwrap" a Promise just to return its value, just wrap it in a new promise either explicity with `Promise.resolve()` or implicitly with `async`.

The reason why this works and your code with this did not work:

```
return new Promise((reject)=> { reject(‘error’); })
```

is that your new promise returns something with type `Promise<{}>`, but returning `Promise.reject(something)` has type `Promise<never>`.

When these are combined with your `Promise<ObjectX>` the first code gives an inferred return type of `Promise<ObjectX | {}>` which cannot be assigned to `Promise<ObjectX>`, but using `Promise.reject()` gives you `Promise<ObjectX | never>` which simplifies down to `Promise<ObjectX>` as the `never` type simply disappears when you combine the types.

If you change the code that didn't work very simply you can see this for yourself as this varient would have worked:

```
return new Promise<never>((reject)=> { reject(‘error’); })
```